# How to add Microsoft App Center to a WPF project using vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, appcenter

This is my first WPF and vb.net application and it is a relatively simple one (an automated form). I would like to monitor its use and the way to do that seems to be Microsoft App Center.  I've logged into App Center, gone to Visual Studio and added the packages for `Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics` and `Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes`. I've added the lines `Imports Microsoft.AppCenter`, `Imports Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics` and `Imports Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes` to the top of MainWindow.xaml.vb. I'm unsure what the vb.net equivalent of `AppCenter.Start("{Your app secret here}", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes))` would be or where to put it. I have the app secret, but would be grateful for any assistance?

I don't know how App Center should work, so I tried adding `AppCenter.Start("{Your app secret here}", GetType(Analytics), GetType(Crashes))` to the `MainWindow_SourceInitialized` event and this did not seem to result in data being shown in App Center.

Comment: Your VB translation of the C# looks correct.  I don't know where you should put it, but I would expect any docs on that for C# to convert directly to VB.

Comment: I seem to have successfully installed Microsoft.AppCenter, Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics and Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.  I have added the app secret, so I have something along the lines of AppCenter.Start("icantpostthis", GetType(Analytics), GetType(Crashes)) in the code for MainWindow_SourceInitialized.  My application runs without errors, but there is nothing under analytics in https://appcenter.ms/users/cant.post-outlook.com/apps/Test-App/analytics/overview.  I expected I would see some data appear when I run my app?

Comment: I've tried putting AppCenter.Start("icantpostthis", GetType(Analytics), GetType(Crashes)) in the Initialized, SourceInitialized and Loaded events, but had no luck with seeing any analytics.